# Is there any way to set sasl.enabled.mechanisms via environment variable on kafka broker?

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, configuration, sasl

I am launching a kafka broker and I need to set the property `sasl.enabled.mechanisms` via an environment variable (or some other method) on startup, instead of via the config file used on start-up.

I tried the environment variable `KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS` but it was not captured.
I also tried via `KAFKA_OPTS= -Dsasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN` but it was not captured as well.

I know both tries did not work because I keep getting this error when connecting to the broker: `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.IllegalSaslStateException: Unexpected handshake request with client mechanism PLAIN, enabled mechanisms are []`

Is there any way to do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM flags aren't passed on to the broker config

If you want to use environment variables, you would have to inject some templating process prior to starting the broker, similar to how many Kafka Docker containers work

You could modify or wrap `kafka-server-start` to read the environment and re-write the config file